# MySQL :- Adding where clause to this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 queries but I confused where to add where clause.

```
select supplier_id,count(*) c, party_name, SUM(po_value) po_value
from purchase_order join supplier s on s.id=supplier_id
group by supplier_id
having c>1 ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 5
```

Second query

```
select warehouse_id, warehouse_name, SUM(available_quantity) available_quantity
from stock join warehouse s on s.id=warehouse_id 
group by warehouse_id
```

In both the queries finally I have to fetch based upon a id like `where org_id='152'`

Comment: Before the group by.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a `GROUP BY` clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function. (I.e. your group by's are invalid. Will not execute on newer MySQL versions.)

Comment: @jarlh I tried and I failed so thats way I  posted it :(

Comment: What failed? The where clause, or the group by?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the edited query below:

```
select supplier_id,count(*) c, party_name, SUM(po_value) po_value
from purchase_order join supplier s on s.id=supplier_id

    WHERE purchase_order.org_id='152

group by supplier_id
having c>1 ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 5
```

This compares against an `org_id` in `purchase_order` use s.org_id if you want to do the looking in the other table.

For the second one

```
select warehouse_id, warehouse_name, SUM(available_quantity) available_quantity
from stock join warehouse s on s.id=warehouse_id 

    WHERE org_id='152


group by warehouse_id
```

(note that whitespace is collapsible). For full details see the manual section on select: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: getting error like before I tried    Error Code: 1052. Column 'org_id' in where clause is ambiguous –

Comment: You didn't mention that you have the same column in both tables. From which table do you want to check the condition?

Comment: Yes so how could I archive this?

Comment: see the edit and also see : "From which table do you want to check the condition?"

Comment: Yes Great:) I was also confused before.

Comment: glad to have been of help

Answer (score 2):

Add it just before the GROUP BY:

```
    SELECT supplier_id,count(*) c, party_name, SUM(po_value) po_value
    FROM purchase_order A JOIN supplier s ON s.id=supplier_id
    GROUP BY supplier_id
    WHERE A.org_id='152'
    HAVING c>1 ORDER BY c DESC LIMIT 5
```

and

```
    SELECT warehouse_id, warehouse_name, SUM(available_quantity) available_quantity
    FROM stock G JOIN warehouse s ON s.id=warehouse_id 
    WHERE G.org_id='152'
    GROUP BY warehouse_id
```

Also, from a readability perspective, I would recommend using capitals to mark out the standard SQL terms :)

The question you have asked is also answered quite nicely by the first example on this page:

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

EDIT: Updated to remove ambiguity on where clause.

Comment: I tried like anything same exception    Error Code: 1052. Column 'org_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: That is because you have the same column in both tables probably. I have edited my code to hopefully remove the ambiguity but it assumed you want to filter it by the 'org_id' column within the FROM table.

Comment: Yes so how could I archive this?

Comment: I have edited my code above; try it and let me know :)

Comment: Great job @Mark Townsend for clarifying my mistake also for the query.